# How can I get my csh alias to work in bash?

Tags: bash, alias, csh

This alias works fine in `/bin/csh`  but not in `/bin/bash`:

```
alias cd='chdir !* && setprompt; clear;  ls -F'
```

Basically, I would like to `cd` to any directory and `ls` in color.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entierly sure what `setprompt` does, but aliases in `bash` can't take arguments like your `csh` alias does (with `!*`). Aliases in the `bash` shell are much simpler than in `csh` and only provide something that amounts to a basic text replacement facility for the command line.

Instead, you'd write a short shell function to overload the `cd` utility:

```bsh
cd () {
    command cd "$1" && clear && ls -F
}
```

or, on a single line,

```bsh
cd () { command cd "$1" && clear && ls -F; }
```

This shell function declaration would go wherever you declare aliases in `bash` (probably in `~/.bashrc`).

It takes a single argument, which is available in the function as `"$1"`.  It calls `command cd` with this as an argument.  We use `command cd` rather than just `cd` to avoid calling your shell function recursively.

The `cd` command changes directory, and if that is successful, `clear` is called and the directory listing is produced using `ls -F`.

Comment: Parameterizable aliases in non-csh alike shells exist longer than functions in Bourne Shell/ksh. They have been introduced in 1980 and based on a shell builtin command `dosh`, that allows to get the functionality of  `sh -c cmd` without a need to create a new process. See Bourne Shell Man Page at: http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html

Comment: @schily Interesting, though this is about setting up a work-alike thing  in `bash`, not in `bosh` or any other shell.

Comment: It is just a note about the fact that a comparable feature existed before functions have been available and tat there are other methods to get that behavior. I still prefer parameterized aliases before functions because there are persistent aliases (also missing from bash) that make aliases easier to use.

Comment: Thank you , that fix it. cd () { command cd "$1" && clear && ls -F --color=auto; }